# Install p7b on apache

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, p7b

I got one certificate from the service provider ( We need to consume the service from server for single sign on)
certificate is p7b format certificate.
Dont know how to install it on apache. Can anyone help to install certificate.

I got allready one certificate on apache, that is crt certificate.

Answer (score 1):

p7b file contains one or several certificates (which supposedly make a certificate chain in your case) without private keys. There's no need to install them on your server - these certificates are used to check the server's authenticity when you connect to it as a client. This is unrelated to your apache.